# Docker Container communicating with M5Atom

Tags: macos, docker, arduino

I would like to make a Docker Container communicating with M5Atom.

Arduino IDE recognizes a Serial Port of M5Atom as `/dev/cu.usbserial-1D4EB11EF3`.

These are results to print the ports.

```
$ ls /dev/cu.*
/dev/cu.usbserial-1D4EB11EF3
/dev/cu.URT0
```

```
$ ls /dev/tty*
/dev/tty.URT0
/dev/tty.usbserial-1D4EB11EF3
```

I try to run a docker container with device options and catch following error.

```
$ docker run --device=/dev/cu.usbserial-1D4EB11EF3:/dev/usbdevice ubuntu:20.04
```

Error message:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: error gathering device information while adding custom device "/dev/cu.usbserial-1D4EB11EF3": no such file or directory.
```

What should I do?

Comment: What OS do you use, MacOS, Windows os Linux?

Comment: I use macOS (Intel)